# doesn't test all code when fixing my string index out range

Tags: python

Okay so the following code is supposed to test whether or not r and b are alternating. So a test of "rbrbrb" would be accepted but "rbbrbbr" would not be accepted.

However my issue is that only tests the first two under def manufactoria()

```
def manufactoria():
  test(alternating_colors, "")
  test(alternating_colors, "r")
  test(alternating_colors, "rb")
  test(alternating_colors, "rbrbrbr") 
  test(alternating_colors, "b") 
  test(alternating_colors, "brbr") 
  test(alternating_colors, "brbrbrbr") 

def alternating_colors(string):
    length = len(string)
    check = 0 
    if len(string) == 0 or len(string)==1:
        return True
    while check <= len(string)-1:
        if string[check]+string[check+1] == "rr" or string[check]+string[check+1] == "bb":
            return False
    check +=1
def test(fn, string):

    if fn(string):
        result = "accepted"
    else:
        result = "not accepted"


    print('The string "' + string + '" is ' + result)

manufactoria()
```

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do here, but if string(check)+string(check+1) == "rr" or string[check]+string[check+1] == "bb" looks totally busted

Comment: Your posted code doesn't run: `test` is undefined.  I fixed your original indentation.  please do the same with your update.

Comment: if `check` is equal to `len(string)-1` and you use an index `string[check+1]` of course you will be out of range, because Python starts counting from 0. Also strings are not callable, so `string(check)` will result in an error, too

Comment: So I tried to change everything in string(check)+ string(check+1) etc to string[check] + string[check+1] but still doesn't test everything. Just tests the first two.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Have you also changed `while check<=len(string)-1` to `while check<=len(string)-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version:

```
def alternating_colors(s):
    length=len(s)
    if length<2:
        return True
    for i in range(length-1):
        curr_slice = s[i:i+2]
        if curr_slice in ["rr", "bb"]:
            return False
    return True
```

This is basically using most of what Prune answered.

An even better solution is using regular expressions. This will find any repetition of either r or b:

```
import re
def alternating_colors(s):
    if re.search(r"r{2,}|b{2,}", s):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: It's about half, but appropriate to the current coding level.  A two-clause use of `in` reduces this to a one-line `return` statement.

Comment: But wouldn't that code accept stuff that's rr and bb? So like in an extended rbrbbr <- given what you said, this would also return as being accepted

Comment: If you plug in `"rr"` or `"bb"` this will return `False`; do I understand you correctly?

Comment: It should return False. But I just tried it and it returned as being accepted.

Comment: I just restarted the kernel and tried this function on `"rr"` and `"bb"` and in both cases it returns `False`

Comment: Hm. Maybe I miss typed it. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: I updated it for a faster and way more beautiful solution, please accept the answer if you are pleased ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't check all of your code because the "index out of range" exception kills your program.

Your index is out of range because you tried to access position 2 of a string of length 2: `"rb"` has indices 0 and 1, but you tried to check `string[1] + string[1+1]`.  You need to stop your checking loop one index earlier, as one commenter already mentioned.

You can make this program shorter and easier to maintain if you learn to use these Python language features:

- < (less than operator)
- `for` statement (replaces your `while` and
  increment loop)
- string slicing (instead of concatenating individual
  characters)
- `in` operator (instead of checking individual locations)

Comment: But I thought you had to use == or <= for some of these statements. It gives me an error message otherwise. How would I change it using a for loop? Would it be somewhere along the lines of 

for check in range(string):
      [code here]

and I don't know what string slicing is vs concatenating individual characters

Comment: These are questions you try to answer for yourself before asking here, as it says in the posting guidelines.  Python tutorials are readily available to cover these concepts.